# Creating a dynamic tree array from another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, lets call it $childrenIds, it outputs as follows:

```
array(

[74252] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1753
        [1] => 1757
        [2] => 1758
        [3] => 1760
    )

[74238] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1753
        [1] => 1755
        [2] => 1758
        [3] => 1761
    )

[76476] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1754
        [1] => 1755
        [2] => 1758
        [3] => 1763
    )

[76478] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1754
        [1] => 1756
        [2] => 1758
        [3] => 1763
    )

[76480] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1754
        [1] => 1757
        [2] => 1758
        [3] => 1763
    )

[74253] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1753
        [1] => 1757
        [2] => 1759
        [3] => 1760
    )
```

);
What i need to do is create a new array from this, where the e.g. [74252] is ignored,
but the children of each sub array are pathed...

So using this example my output would be something like:
    array(

```
[1753] => Array
(
    [1757] => Array
    (
        [1758] => Array
        (
            1760
        ),
        [1759] => Array
        (
            1760
        ),
    )
    [1755] =>  Array
        (
            1758 =>  Array
            (
                1761
            )
        )
    )
),
[1754] => Array
(
    [1755] => Array
    (
        [1758] => Array
        (
            1763
        )
    ),
    [1756] => Array
    (
        [1758] => Array
        (
            1763
        )
    ),
    [1757] => Array
    (
        [1758] => Array
        (
            1763
        )
    )
)
);
```

So there will not always be 4 sub array elements, that is dynamic...

The parents are just based on the index of that array. So... index[0] is the parent of index[1], index[1] is the parent of index[2] and so forth.

Also, I want to end up with all UNIQUE paths, no duplicate values per path.

Hopefully I have explained this clearly, been searching for a few hours and can't find a solution that meets all of my requires, if I overlooked one, I apologize in advance.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

As opposed to passing an array I ended up passing an underscore delimited string, then using this function:

```
function explodeTree($array, $delim = '/')
{
$tree = array();

foreach($array as $elem)
{
    //  Split our string up, and remove any blank items
    $items = explode($delim, $elem);
    $items = array_diff($items, array(''));

    //  current holds the current position in the tree
    $current = &$tree;

    foreach($items as $item)
    {
        //  If we've not created this branch before, or there is
        //  a leaf with the same name, then turn it into a branch
        if(!isset($current[$item]) || !is_array($current[$item]))
        {
            $current[$item] = array();
        }

        //  Update our current position to the branch we entered
        //  (or created, depending on the above if statement)
        $current = &$current[$item];
    }

    //  If the last value in this row is an array with 0 elements
    //  then (for now) we will consider it a leaf node, and set it
    //  to be equal to the string representation that got us here.
    if(count($current) == 0)
    {
        $current = $elem;
    }
}

return $tree;
}
```

found @:
http://project-2501.net/index.php/2007/10/explodetree/
AND:
http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/convert_anything_to_tree_structures_in_php/

I was able to obtain the desired result.

Comment: How are the children of each item "pathed"? What's the logic? Why - in the resulting array - 1753 has 1755 ans 1757 as children? (and not something else)

Comment: Sorry ... the parents are just based on the index of that array. So... index[0] is the parent of index[1], index[1] is the parent of index[2] and so forth.

Comment: So you need something like `(1753->1757->1758->1760, 1754->1755->1758->1763, ...)`? Be careful so that we are talking about the same thing....

Comment: Yes I believe so,
however the next would be
1754-1756->1758->1763

Comment: OK, let's say we take 3 elements of your initial MAIN array (..252,..238,..476) ... and convert them... how many elements in our NEW MAIN array will that make?

Comment: I'm sorry it's too confusing; I still don't get it...

Comment: if you took the first 3 elements of my MAIN array you would end up with...
1753->1757->1758->1760, 
1754->1755->1758->1763
    ->1756->1758->1763

Comment: Well... I finally did something. Let's see how close I am... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first element in the array:

```
[74252] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1753
        [1] => 1757
        [2] => 1758
        [3] => 1760
    )
```

The paths represented are basically

```
[0] => 1753
[1] => 1753/1757
[2] => 1753/1757/1758
[3] => 1753/1757/1758/1760
```

You could probably solve with something like this (not tested). The explodeTree function is from http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/convert_anything_to_tree_structures_in_php/ and I'm assuming that it works as advertised. Never used it myself.

```
$pathArray = array();
foreach($startArray as $subArray) {
    $pathStr = '';

    foreach($subArray as $v) {
        $pathStr = $pathStr.'/'.$v;
        $pathArray[]=$pathStr;
    }        
}

$pathArray = array_unique($pathArray);
$treeArray = explodeTree($pathArray, "/");
```

Comment: You set me on the right path... i found a solution via google here... http://project-2501.net/index.php/2007/10/explodetree/, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**Code :** ***(UPDATED)***

```
$newarr = array();

function getElem($sub,$n)
{
    $res = array();

    if ($n==count($sub)-1)
        $res[]=$sub[$n];
    else
        $res[$sub[$n]] = getElem($sub,$n+1);

    return $res;
}

foreach ($arr as $subarr)
{
    $newarr[$subarr[0]] = getElem($subarr,1);
}

print_r($newarr);
```

---

**Input :**

```
$arr=
array(

74252 => Array
    (
        0 => 1753,
        1 => 1757,
        2 => 1758,
        3 => 1760
    ),

74238 => Array
    (
        0 => 1753,
        1 => 1755,
        2 => 1758,
        3 => 1761
    ),

76476 => Array
    (
        0 => 1754,
        1 => 1755,
        2 => 1758,
        3 => 1763
    ),

76478 => Array
    (
        0 => 1754,
        1 => 1756,
        2 => 1758,
        3 => 1763
    )
);
```

**Output :**

```
Array
(
    [1753] => Array
        (
            [1755] => Array
                (
                    [1758] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1761
                        )

                )

        )

    [1754] => Array
        (
            [1756] => Array
                (
                    [1758] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1763
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Well that is the desired output!  However there are many more than the 5 elements of my main array that I shared with you, and the number of sub elements will also vary.  I appreciate the effort though.

Comment: @Jim Give me a sec, and I'll make it handle variable sub elements too.

Comment: @Jim I just updated my answer... it'll now work for ANY elements in the main array, and for ANY number of sub-elements... :-)

Comment: wow, first off thanks a lot for the time / effort...
unfortunately its not quite there, so the problem is that it needs to detect if the parent array exists down each path, and if it does, not overwrite it, but a append a child with the path

Comment: @Jim Maybe try giving me a precise example?

Comment: so for example with your input, the 1754 element gets overwritten each time, when really I need it to traverse down the array until there is a unique value, so 1756 would have a brother -> 1755->1758->1763

Comment: @Jim hmmm... is that "brother" thing valid for all sublevels? (let's say 1754 is level 1 and 1755/1756 level... is that valid even for their children?)

Comment: @Jim OK, I think I'm even closer to what you have in mind. What I have  to say is that it's **REALLY** complicated - give me some time to think (it's 7:32 in the morning here, so bare with me...).

Comment: Yes I believe i Did, so instead of passing in the main array, I can pass in an underscore delimitted string... then using the explodeTree() function found here... http://project-2501.net/index.php/2007/10/explodetree/

Comment: Thanks for all of your time dr.

Comment: @Jim You're welcome! (I was about to burn my head out, with like 2 recursions one into the other... lol)

Comment: yeah i've been looking / thinking about it for about 6 hours now.  My head is burnt.  Updated my question with the solution if you are interested.

Comment: @Jim The "weird" consequences of globalization : "My head is burnt" now too. lol. Have a nice day, from Greece! ;-) Time to sleep a little...